# Sublime Text - Regular Expression for search and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to use search & replace with a regular expression to turn the following text:

"some text i dont care about `\cite[p. 6]{some-bibtex-citation}` some more text I care even less about \cite[p. 321 / 4]{and-another-citation-from-bibxtex} and still more text."

into this:

"some text i dont care about `[\citem{author}{some-bibtex-citation}, p. 6]` some more text I care even less about `[\citem{author}{and-another-citation-from-bibxtex}, p. 321 / 4]` and still more text."

As you can see, all of the \cite occurences have been replaced with a different one. They are now surrounded by [ and ] and they all start with [citem{author}

I tried it with the following search regex which basically works but can select too much text all at once:

```
\\cite\[(.+)\]\{(.+)\}
```

The replace regex I used for this is:

```
[\\citem{author}{\2}, \1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but can select too much text all at once"?

Comment: it's supposed to select until the closing curly braces. For Example: it's supposed to stop after -citation} but it will select the text that comes afterwards ("some more text ...") aswell

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change your regex so that the `.+` becomes lazy:

```
\\cite\[(.+?)\]\{(.+?)\}
           ^        ^
```

Making a greedy quantifier lazy means that instead of matching as much as possible, it will match as little as possible. In your current regex, the `.` will match all the characters until it finds another `)` (followed by the other characters in the regex).

Or use negated classes:

```
\\cite\[([^\]]+)\]\{([^}]+)\}
```

Comment: some might call this "lazy" evaluation non greedy

Comment: The negated classes were what was needed for my use case. Thanks!